# Use cut to cut a field via user input

Tags: bash, shell

I need to create a bash script that will cut a column from a data file that has been requested by a user (input). The script needs to prompt a field that will become a variable used to cut the field requested. This is one of the scripts that I have tried:

```
$x = cut -c example_list
echo -n "What column would you like to cut: "
set x = $<
```

Comment: And the problem with what you've tried is...? Why are you prompting for a value and then not using it?

Comment: I am not sure of the best way to get the user input via the cut command. I need to run this script from the command line and have it execute with a user prompt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get user input using `read`:

```
echo -n "What column would you like to cut: "
read col
cut -f $col ...
```

Comment: When I run this script via command line, how can I get this script to run and read a file that's located in a specific directory?

Comment: `cut -f $col path/to/file...`

Answer (score 1):

You could use an `awk` script. It's a lot more powerful than `cut`. Run like `awk -f script.awk file.txt`

Contents of `script.awk`:

```
BEGIN {
    printf "Enter a column: "
    getline col < "-"
}

{
    print $col
}
```

Alternatively, here's the one-liner:

```
awk 'BEGIN { printf "Enter a column: "; getline col < "-" } { print $col }' file.txt
```

Comment: Steve thank you for you awk script. I will use it for some other projects that I have.